# Get post_id with the highest count of rows from table

Tags: mysql

I have a "visit" table where views are stored, so every time someone opens my page it adds a row to my database with the post_id - how can I now determine which site (post_id) has the most views?

I have tried

```sql
SELECT post_id as idpro, count(*) as count FROM visits group by post_id
```

but it is not showing me the highest and is not sorted by "showing the highest first"

Comment: You need to add an `order by count desc`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `order by  count  DESC limit 1`

```
SELECT post_id as idpro, count(*) as count FROM visits group by post_id order by  count  DESC limit 1
```

Comment: it shows count 1, that cant be the highest, i have a total view of 10000

Comment: I need the post_id which has the most rows

Comment: what is the result without limit for the above query ?

Comment: looks like it works perfectly without the limit, any idea on how to connect the query to the other table? in the post table I have the post_id, but I also need the unique_id from table "posts"

Comment: in my case it also work with limit, so in your case just use first result

Comment: Exactly, but can you also help me with the issue I asked above your comment?

Comment: i mean you are using query with any backend language, so use the first row of result

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `order by count desc` To sort the `count` column with highest values on top

```
SELECT post_id, 
       count(*) as c
  FROM visits
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY c DESC
```

Comment: remove from here and add as comment, this is not the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

ad `as table alias name`

```
SELECT MAX(count) 
FROM (SELECT post_id as idpro,COUNT(post_id) count
FROM visits 
GROUP BY post_id ) as test;
```

Comment: I get an error: 1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias